# NPE in ArrayAdapter, createViewFromResource

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

I have autocomplete field, which get suggestions from google places api. 
And in google play console I found some exceptions from users, related to ArrayAdapter.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource (ArrayAdapter.java:445)
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView (ArrayAdapter.java:407)
  at fragment.common.PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.getView (PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java:2)
  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView (AbsListView.java:3189)
  at android.widget.DropDownListView.obtainView (DropDownListView.java:323)
  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView (ListView.java:2197)
```

Full code of my ArrayAdapter:

```
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
    extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

private final LatLng currentLocation;

private List<AutocompletePrediction> resultList;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LatLngBounds bounds;
private AutocompleteFilter placeFilter;

public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(final Context context, final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                final LatLngBounds bounds, final AutocompleteFilter filter,
                                final LatLng currentLocation) {
    super(context, Layouts.AUTOCOMPLETE_ROW_LAYOUT, Layouts.AUTOCOMPLETE_ROW_ADDRESS);
    this.googleApiClient = googleApiClient;
    this.bounds = bounds;
    this.placeFilter = filter;
    this.currentLocation = currentLocation;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resultList != null ? resultList.size() : 0;
}

@Override
public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
    if (position < 0 || getCount() - 1 < position) {
        return  null;
    }
    return resultList.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);
    if (item == null) {
        return row;
    }

    final TextView addressText = row.findViewById(Layouts.AUTOCOMPLETE_ROW_ADDRESS);
    final TextView distanceText = row.findViewById(Layouts.AUTOCOMPLETE_ROW_DISTANCE);

    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, item.getPlaceId());
    placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onResult(@NonNull final PlaceBuffer places) {
                                          if (currentLocation != null && places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.get(0) != null) {
                                              Place place = places.get(0);
                                              double distance = Distance.getDistance(currentLocation, place.getLatLng()) / 1000;
                                              distanceText.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.distanceStats, Parameters.DISTANCE_FORMAT.format(distance)));
                                          }
                                          places.release();
                                      }
                                  }
    );

    addressText.setText(item.getPrimaryText(null));
    return row;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null) {
                resultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                if (resultList != null) {
                    results.values = resultList;
                    results.count = resultList.size();
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getPrimaryText(null);
            } else {
                return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
            }
        }
    };
}

private List<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getAutocompletePredictions(googleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                bounds, placeFilter);

        AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                .await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return null;
        }

        return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I don't understand why it can happens, on different devices and different android versions. And I can not reproduce it on my device.

Comment: I do not think that `ArrayAdapter` has changed too much recently, so [this is probably the line that you are crashing on](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-8.1_r6/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L445). This would occur if `getItem()` for some valid `position` returned `null`.

Comment: May be. I should return some empty AutocompletePrediction instead null it this case?

Comment: Or I think, I can stop calling ` super.getView`

Comment: You could skip `super.getView()` and inflate/recycle the row layout yourself, if you wish. However, your code is set up to then return an otherwise-empty `View` from `getView()`, if `getItem()` returns `null`. While this should be safe, it may result in an odd user experience (e.g., an empty row in the autocomplete list). You may want to see what the Places API is supposed to return. If a "no results found" answer is a list with a `null` entry or something, perhaps you could filter that out of your data set.